# AFNetworking install via cocoa pods issue

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I install this framework [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) using next specification pointed in Podfile as in description on git:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
```

But when I run project I had this error:

dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/BD91CA1D-5AC2-4187-9559-BD7F9F45866F/Test.app/Test
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
 in /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/BD91CA1D-5AC2-4187-9559-BD7F9F45866F/Test.app/Test

I installed AFNetworking before but there were not issues like this. I see that compiler says about `NSURLSession` that is supported on iOS 7 as I think, but on git I read next:

**AFNetworking 2.0 officially supports iOS 6+, Mac OS X 10.8+, and Xcode 5.**

So how to fix this issue?

Comment: try removing the platform line in the pod file? I'm guessing if you say its iOS 7 only AFNetworking pod doesn't link the iOS 6 compatible classes

Comment: seems it works, i have remove this line and run pod install

Comment: cool, added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the platform line in the Podfile, AFNetworking pod spec will only link in iOS 6 classes if your target requires them

Comment: @KunalKumar AFNetworking has dropped support for iOS 6, so if you still need support you will need to use an older release (2.5.4 or older)